# Drupal Access to Admin panel Denied

Tags: drupal

Inserted new menu item in hook_menu. But the menu item is not reflected. So in module i added the statement as

```
function {module_name}_menu_alter(&$items) {
    $items['archives/faculty_article'] = array(
           'access callback'=>'archives_list_faculty_article',
         'access arguments'=>array(1),
        );
    $items['archives/faculty_article']['access callback'] = 'user_access';
}
```

Problem raised
1. Not able to access admin panel
2. user warning: Table 'nodewords_custom' doesn't exist query: `SELECT * FROM nodewords_custom ORDER BY weight ASC`

How can I correct the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you flushed your menu cache after creating your new menu entry in the hook_menu()? It's mandatory if you want your new menu entry to be evaluated.

About your code snippet in the hook_menu_alter(), you are not altering properly the menu item, either your rewrite the full attributes of the item (title, page callback, access callback etc) either you just override one attribute (such as what you did for the access callback).
If you want to override two attributes you have to do something like that:

```
$items['archives/faculty_article']['access callback'] = 'user_access';
$items['archives/faculty_article']['access arguments'] = array('view');
```

After implementing the hook_menu_alter() you also have to flush your caches.

That's for problem 1. For problem 2, it means that you didn't install nodewords correctly, try to disabling it, uninstalling it and then re-enabling it to try to fix the issue. It should recreate the table for you.

Comment: Thanks. News to drupal. How can I flush cache. I tried drupal_flush_all_caches();. Then too admin panel access is denied.

Comment: To flush your caches go to admin/settings/performance, at the bottom of the page there is a button to flush caches.
If you are using the admin_menu module you have a shortcut to flush the caches on the drupalicon menu item (first top left corner)

Comment: Admin access is denied how can I flush cache or enable or re-enable nodewords

Comment: You can also flush the cache (and other admin tasks) outside of Drupal by using Drush. This allows you to perform admin tasks even when you can't log in to the actual site as admin.

Comment: Humm your right, you can flush the menu cache by running this query in your sql CLI or in PhpMyAdmin: `TRUNCATE cache_menu`